# Windows.UI.Xaml.Media ==> There are no brushes

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime

I need your help. Im working on an application with canvas.

```
class Amobe : Lebenwesen
{
    public override void Zeichne(Canvas dieCanvas)
    {
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.Width  = 5.0;
        ellipse.Height = 5.0;
        dieCanvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
        Canvas.SetLeft(dieCanvas, x - 2.5);
        Canvas.SetTop(dieCanvas, x - 2.5);
    } 
}
```

Now, I want to fill the Ellipse. So I try:

```
ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Green;
```

I get the Error that "the Name "Brushes" don't exist in the current context". So I Imported Windows.Media and Windows.UI.Xaml.Media, but it still don't work.

Thanks for help,
Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be Windows Runtime, not WPF, as you import `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media`.

Windows Runtime does not have a `Brushes` class. You'll have to explicitly create a `SolidColorBrush` instance:

```
using Windows.UI;
...
ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

---

Besides that, you'll have to call SetLeft and SetTop on the Ellipse, not on the Canvas:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, x - 2.5);
Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, x - 2.5);
```

Comment: Thanks:D But Now, I get the Error that "Colors" don't exist in the current contest/:

Comment: Arent't you using Visual Studio? It shows you a blue marker below the Colors identfifer, and if you click that or press `Ctrl`+`.` it opens a popup menu where you can select the namespace to use. In this case it's `Windows.UI`.